# Windows batch file sending sigint to python script

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file

I'm using a windows .bat file to run two python scripts, each script has handling for `SIGINT` to close cleanly, as they are writing to files.

This is not the case when I execute the .bat file, is there a way to, on receiving Ctrl+c, send a `SIGINT` to the python scripts.

The python scripts in question are for measuring sensor streams and writing the data to a tsv file, I won't write the entire script here but functionally it is equivalent to

```py
import serial
import signal
import time
from datetime import datetime, timezone

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    global interrupted
    interrupted = True


signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
interrupted = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serialPort = serial.Serial(port='COM4', baudrate=9600)
    serialString = ""

    t = round(time.time())
    filename = f'gps_{t}.tsv'
    print(f"Writing to {filename}")
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write("time\tnmea\n")
        while True:
            if serialPort.in_waiting > 0:
                t = time.time()
                serialString = serialPort.readline()[:-2].decode('Ascii')
                f.write(f"{t}\t{serialString}\n")

            if interrupted:
                print("Breaking gnss loop...")
                break
```

and the BAT file is just

```
START "" /B "C:\Users\nisso\anaconda3\envs\sensor_logging\python.exe" "C:/Users/nisso/Desktop/sensor_logging/gnss_reader.py"
START "" /B "C:\Users\nisso\anaconda3\envs\sensor_logging\python.exe" "C:/Users/nisso/Desktop/sensor_logging/imu_reader.py"

cmd /c exit 3221225786
```

I basically only use linux, windows here is a necessity due to another sensor with some proprietary software, so my knowledge of batch files and the like is extremely limited.

Answer (score 1):

The signal `SIGINT` (or `SIGBREAK`) sent on pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> by Windows to console application in foreground with input focus is processed in this case first by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file and results in prompting the user if the batch job should be terminated or not.

`python.exe` would be the next process in process hierarchy, but it does not get this signal as `cmd.exe` is receiving and handling it first. See the Microsoft documentation for [CTRL+C and CTRL+BREAK Signals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-break-signals).

It is possible to use `%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe` **without** using option `/F` to send to a specific `python.exe` process identified by its process identifier (pid) the [CTRL+CLOSE Signal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ctrl-close-signal) (console applications) respectively the [WM_CLOSE message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close) (GUI applications). See also the Microsoft documentation for [Registering a Control Handler Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/registering-a-control-handler-function).

It looks like there are several requirements to handle by the batch file for this task:

1. The batch file should not be used only for starting the two Python processes which are endless running until Python gets the terminate or interrupt signal, but also for terminating the two Python processes on user pressing a key like <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> in the console window opened for `cmd.exe` processing the batch file.
2. The two Python scripts print information to the standard output stream which the user should be able to read.
3. There can be already running one or more `python.exe` process on starting the two Python processes and it could even happen that another process starts a `python.exe` process while `cmd.exe` is processing the batch file and starting the two Python processes. That requires special code to get the process identifiers of the two Python processes really started by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file.
4. It would be best if both Python processes use the console window of `cmd.exe` processing the batch file for their output to standard output stream.

These requirements are hard to fulfill with a batch file interpreted by the Windows command processor which is not really designed for such complex process management tasks. It would be much better to code a third Python script which does the following:

1. Use [sys.executable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) to get the full qualified file name of the Python executable interpreting this third Python script.
2. Use `os.path.realpath(__file__)` to get the full path of the directory with the third Python script currently executed which contains also the Python scripts `gnss_reader.py` and `imu_reader.py`.
3. Use [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) using on Windows the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) and the structure [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) to open two child processes with the Python executable file name and the script file path concatenated with `gnss_reader.py` respectively `imu_reader.py` as arguments and with specifying the current working directory with script file path.

That gives the third Python script the full control what is output to the console window opened on starting `python.exe` with the third Python script file. The third Python script has also the full control how to gracefully terminate the two Python subprocesses when the third Python script file terminates itself because of a signal from parent process or the operating system or a user input offered by third Python script for termination.

I am not a Python programmer and for that reason have not coded the Python solution.
But I can offer two possible batch file solutions.

---

The first batch file uses [WMIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic) with [Create method of the Win32_Process class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/create-method-in-class-win32-process) to start the two Python processes with the appropriate Python script file as argument and the directory of the batch file set as current working directory for the two Python processes.

The advantage of this batch file solution is that `wmic` returns information of created process containing the `ProcessId` which can be read from the standard output of the `cmd.exe` instance started in background by **FOR** respectively the `cmd.exe` processing the batch file to execute the `wmic` command line.

The disadvantage of this solution is that for each Python process one more console window is opened and for that reason the fourth requirement is not fulfilled by this solution.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq skip=5 tokens=2 delims=;= " %%I in (`%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PROCESS CALL Create '"%UserProfile%\anaconda3\envs\sensor_logging\python.exe" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\sensor_logging\gnss_reader.py"'^, "%~dp0"`) do set "PythonPIDs=/PID %%I" & goto StartSecond
:StartSecond
for /F "usebackq skip=5 tokens=2 delims=;= " %%I in (`%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PROCESS CALL Create '"%UserProfile%\anaconda3\envs\sensor_logging\python.exe" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\sensor_logging\imu_reader.py"'^, "%~dp0"`) do set "PythonPIDs=%PythonPIDs% /PID %%I" & goto WaitTerminate
:WaitTerminate
echo(
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C CE /N /M "Terminate with C or E ..."
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe %PythonPIDs%
endlocal
pause
```

The user of the batch file can press <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>E</kbd> or even <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and answer the prompt by `cmd.exe` to terminate the batch job with <kbd>N</kbd> to continue batch file processing with command **TASKKILL** to terminate the two started Python processes.

This solution was tested with a console application written by me and which was started instead of `python.exe` which waited for a key press by the user for self-termination, but being gracefully terminated by **TASKKILL**.

---

The second batch file solution expects that no other `python.exe` instance is started while `cmd.exe` starts the two Python processes as specified in the batch file. The batch file directory is again used as current working directory for `python.exe`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "PythonPIDs= "
for /F "tokens=2" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq python.exe" /NH 2^>nul') do set "PythonPIDs=!PythonPIDs!%%I "
start "" /B /D "%~dp0" "%UserProfile%\anaconda3\envs\sensor_logging\python.exe" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\sensor_logging\gnss_reader.py"
start "" /B /D "%~dp0" "%UserProfile%\anaconda3\envs\sensor_logging\python.exe" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\sensor_logging\imu_reader.py"
for /F "tokens=2" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq python.exe" /NH 2^>nul') do if "!PythonPIDs: %%I =!" == "!PythonPIDs!" (set "PythonPIDs=!PythonPIDs!%%I ") else set "PythonPIDs=!PythonPIDs: %%I = !"
set "PythonPIDs=!PythonPIDs: = /PID !"
set "PythonPIDs=!PythonPIDs:~1,-5!"
echo(
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C CE /N /M "Terminate with C or E ..."
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe %PythonPIDs%
endlocal
pause
```

This batch file defines first the environment variable `PythonPIDs` with a space separated list of process identifiers of all running `python.exe` processes.

Next the two Python processes are started of which output to standard output stream is written into the console window opened on starting `cmd.exe` processing the batch file.

Then there is run a second time **TASKLIST** to remove all `python.exe` process identifiers already present in string value of environment variable `PythonPIDs` and add the (hopefully just two) process identifiers of the just started Python processes. So the environment variable `PythonPIDs` should be finally defined with the process identifiers of the two Python processes started via the batch file.

There could be another Python PID in string value of `PythonPIDs` in case of one of the Python processes already running on startup of the batch file terminated at the same time as the two Python processes are started by `cmd.exe`. It would be possible to use for the two started Python processes a different environment variable than `PythonPIDs`. But this solution requires in any case that no Python process is started by another process while `cmd.exe` starts the two Python processes. So it can be also assumed that no Python process terminates while the two Python processes are started. This solution will be never perfect regarding to determination of the process identifiers of the two started Python processes.

The termination of the two started Python processes is done in the same manner as by the first batch file.

The graceful termination did not work on my test using the same console application as in first batch file solution waiting for a key press of the user for self-termination. That was no surprise for me because of the two instances of the console application are using same standard input stream as `cmd.exe` processing the batch file and started `choice.exe`. But I hope it works with the Python scripts which do not handle standard input while running.

The option `/B` of command **START** does not mean that `python.exe` is really started as separate process in background with its own standard input, output and error stream without opening a console window. The usage of option `/B` results in starting `python.exe` as child process of `cmd.exe` without opening a new console window, but with using standard input, output and error stream of `cmd.exe`. For that reason a Python solution with a third Python script would be most likely the best solution.

---

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 which is the full path of the directory containing the batch file.
- `choice /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`
- `taskkill /?`
- `tasklist /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic process /?`
- `wmic process call /?`
- `wmic process call create /?`